# Pass dynamic array ponter into func in C ending with "Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)"

Tags: c, pointers, reference, dynamic-arrays

I need to change params char array in parser function, but after leaving parser function params array is still NULL and it ends with "Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#define SSH_BIN_PATH "\usr\bin\ssh"

void parser(char *route[4], char **params);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *route[4];
    char **params = NULL;
    parser(route, params);

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("\nRoute: %s\n", params[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void parser(char *route[4], char **params) {
    char *userAndPass = NULL;
    char *token = NULL;
    int line_count = 0;
    char lines[100][100];


    FILE *file = fopen("/home/user/Documents/format.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Opening failure.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fgets(lines[line_count], sizeof(lines[line_count]), file)) {
        size_t length = strlen(lines[line_count]);
        if (lines[line_count][length - 1] == '\n') {
            lines[line_count][length - 1] = '\0';
        }
        line_count++;
    }

    fclose(file);

    if (strcmp(lines[line_count - 1], "exit") != 0) {
        strcpy(lines[line_count], "exit");
        line_count++;
    }

    params = (char**)malloc(line_count * sizeof(char*));
    if (params == NULL) {
        printf("Memory error.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < line_count; i++) {
        params[i] = strdup(lines[i]);
        if (params[i] == NULL) {
            printf("Memory error.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    token = strtok(params[0], "@");
    if (token != NULL) {
        userAndPass = token;

        token = strtok(NULL, ":");
        if (token != NULL) {
            route[2] = token;

            token = strtok(NULL, "@");
            if (token != NULL) {
                route[3] = token;
            }
        }
    }

    token = strdup(userAndPass);
    token = strtok(token, ":");
    if (token != NULL) {
        route[0] = token;
        if (strlen(userAndPass) != strlen(route[0])) {
            token = strtok(NULL, "@");
            if (token != NULL)
                route[1] = token;
        }
        else
            route[1] = "";
    }
}
```

I can't understand what's a problem, so i even try to do it with 3 pointers like this

```
void parser(char *route[4], char ***params){
  *params = (char**)malloc(line_count * sizeof(char*));
    if (*params == NULL) {
        printf("Memory error.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < line_count; i++) {
        *params[i] = strdup(lines[i]);
        if (*params[i] == NULL) {
            printf("Memory error\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

int main(){ 
  parser(route, &params);
}
```

But it didn't help

Comment: Please edit the question adding a sample of the input file. The code that deals with `userAndPass` sure feels wrong. Also, the parser is not affecting the value stored in the main function's `params`. Do you know how to return a pointer from a function?

Comment: The original `parser` is totally wrong, the modified `parser` has an operator precedence error (need `(*params)[i]` rather than `*params[i]`, didn't search for additional errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question it seems that you are aware that `params` must by passed as a pointer. In other words, that you first code example is wrong because it passes `params` by value.

You second example is correct with respect to the way `params` is being passed, i.e. pass a pointer to `params` instead of passing the value of `params`.

However, the second example has another serious problem related to `C operator precedence`.

Look at this code:

```
*params[i] = strdup(lines[i]);
```

What is it really doing?

It is like a) `(*params)[i] = strdup(lines[i]);`

or like b) `*(params[i]) = strdup(lines[i]);`

That makes a hugh difference....

The answer is that it is like b) but you actually want it to be a).

So you need to explicit add the parenthesis and use `(*params)[i] = strdup(lines[i]);`

Comment: Thanks for help!! Didn't know about that difference

Comment: @Xhar C operator precedence is important. In most cases it turns out to be "just as one would expect" but sometimes it can be more tricky. For instance, what will this really do: `a == 0 && b == 9 || c == 42 && d == 123` ? You can see a list here https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence Study it....